# Using existing Cloud SQL Table loads slow; Creating Table through AppMaker in Cloud SQL loads fast

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-app-maker

I am using a Cloud SQL database with one table of ~700 records with ~100 fields and it takes 8-10 seconds to load an individual record from the database into AppMaker. This is how long it takes even when I have set the Query Page size to "1".

To test if this was an issue with my database I created an External Model (e.g., new table) in the database through AppMaker. The new table created through AppMaker loads in less than 2 seconds, which is fairly typical load speeds for AppMaker.

Why would my pre-existing table load slowly whereas my table created in the SQL DB through AppMaker load quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only idea that popups in my mind is that you had different regions for the databases. [App Maker's documentation recommends](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql) to create database instance in `us-central` region to achieve best performance. Some time ago I've tried to pair App Maker with database from some European region and it worked fairly slow.